# Missing 'path' argument in get() call

Tags: python, django

I am trying to test my views in Django, and when I run this i get the error

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from foodsystem_app.models import discount,menu
import json

class TestViews(TestCase):
    
    def test_login_GET(self):
        client = Client

        response = client.get(reverse('login'))

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response,'foodsystem/login.html')
```

```
    response = client.get(reverse('login'))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I'm not sure what I am supposed to pass as the path name. This is the code for what I am testing

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}.")
                return redirect("main:homepage")
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="login.html", context={"login_form":form})
```

Comment: You are setting `client` to the `Client` class instead of initializing an instance. Thus the first argument to `get` that is usually `self` is now passed `reverse('login')`. Fix it by adding parentheses: `client = Client()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate the `Client` class, you are currently just referencing the class directly.

```
client = Client()
```